# How to redirect to login page client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

when the session expires i want to redirect to login page. How can it be done on client side events also

Comment: Say Whaaat?
Anyways, keep ajax request in loop, which checks the session state, when the session state changes, redirect to login page from client (javascript redirect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
function redirectme()
{
@if(Session["key"]==null)
{
<text>window.location.href='/Account/Login';</text>
}
}
```

hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done by calling a controller method through javascript and then putting redirect code there in the controller method. This way, javascript will check if the session is expired and if yes, it will call our method, which in turn call the redirection on client side..